# How long does it take for a table to get added to svv_table_info?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'd like to use svv_table_info as a way to calculate the size of a temporary table. I'll use the result to determine whether it is small enough to push over to the production database.

Unfortunately, it appears that there's a delay between when a table is created and when it is available in svv_table_info.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE example_123 as 
SELECT *
FROM existing_table

select * 
from svv_table_info as ti
where ti.table ilike '%example_123%'
```

When I run the query, the second query returns nothing.

How long do I have to wait and is there a more express way to get the table size?

Comment: Is there any data in `existing_table`? SVV_TABLE_INFO doesn't return anything for empty tables. Also you need to be either a superuser or have SELECT privilege on SVV_TABLE_INFO explicitly granted to your user.

Answer (score 0):

There is no delay, something else is preventing you from seeing the table in `svv_table_info`. Perhaps it has no rows? Only tables that contain data are shown in `svv_table_info`.

You can use the tables that the `svv_table_info` view uses to get the data you want directly. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_STV_TBL_PERM.html

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_pk_test;
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_pk_test (
    country VARCHAR,
    state   VARCHAR,
    entries INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (country, state)
);
INSERT INTO tmp_pk_test
VALUES ('USA', '00', 7001)
     , ('USA', '00', 1)
     , ('USA', '01', 20225)
     , ('USA', '02', 22772)
     , ('USA', '03', 4577)
     , ('USA', '04', 17877)
     , ('USA', '05', 19503);

SELECT a.tbl tbl_id , b.tbl_name , c.node
     , SUM(a.tbl_mb)   tbl_mb
     , SUM(b.tbl_rows) tbl_rows
FROM (SELECT tbl, slice, COUNT(*) tbl_mb
        FROM stv_blocklist a
      GROUP BY 1,2) a
JOIN (SELECT id, slice, TRIM(name) tbl_name, SUM(rows) tbl_rows
      FROM stv_tbl_perm 
      GROUP BY 1,2,3) b
ON a.tbl = b.id AND a.slice = b.slice
JOIN stv_slices c ON a.slice = c.slice
WHERE tbl_name LIKE 'tmp%'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3
;
-- tbl_id  |     tbl_name     | node | tbl_mb | tbl_rows
-----------+------------------+------+--------+----------
-- 1231945 | tmp_pk_test      |    0 |     24 |        5
-- 1231945 | tmp_pk_test      |    1 |     24 |        4
```